# Difference between String.getBytes() and IOUtils.toByteArray()?

Tags: java, junit, arrays, apache-commons

I'm testing the IOUtils. I have problems to convert an InputStream into a byte array:

```
private static final String LOREM_IPSUM = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";

@Test
public void testInputStreamToByteArray() throws IOException {

    byte[] expecteds = LOREM_IPSUM.getBytes();
    byte[] actuals = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(new StringInputStream(LOREM_IPSUM));

    assertArrayEquals(expecteds, actuals);
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: array lengths differed, expected.length=56 actual.length=112
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:91)
    at org.junit.internal.ComparisonCriteria.assertArraysAreSameLength(ComparisonCriteria.java:72)
    at org.junit.internal.ComparisonCriteria.arrayEquals(ComparisonCriteria.java:36)
    at org.junit.Assert.internalArrayEquals(Assert.java:414)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertArrayEquals(Assert.java:200)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertArrayEquals(Assert.java:213)
    at [...].testInputStreamToByteArray(HttpsTest.java:20)[...]
```

I do not see why not pass the test. What is wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Specifying the encoding is important.**

You haven't provided any encoding for the libraries to work with, and as a result the "default" encoding will be used instead. I'm guessing that since one of your byte arrays is twice the size of the other, one encoding used is UTF-16 and the other UTF-8/ASCII.

Try this:

```
public void testInputStreamToByteArray() throws IOException {

    byte[] expecteds = LOREM_IPSUM.getBytes("UTF-8");
    byte[] actuals = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(new StringReader(LOREM_IPSUM), "UTF-8");

    assertArrayEquals(expecteds, actuals);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But toByteArray not accept InputStream and String. Two options:
`IOUtils.toByteArray (new StringReader (LOREM_IPSUM), "UTF-8");
IOUtils.toByteArray (new InputStreamReader (is), "UTF-8");`

Comment: Ah, didn't notice that you're using java.io.InputStream. You'll need to use a Reader, or more specifically StringReader:  
`byte[] actuals = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(new StringReader(LOREM_IPSUM), "UTF-8");`

Comment: My comment was just to clarify. Thank you again.